# Universal Windows Deploy issues

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have en issue with a Universal windows problem (Microsoft dynamics Modern POS, if that helps) that can deploy inside visual studio 2017. I can build the project fine, but this is the error i get from the output when I attempt to debug the project:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: Pos.App, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>Parameter cannot be null or whitespace.
1>Parameter name: packageRecipe
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I double checked that my SDK are correct and made sure I uninstalled the POS befire trying to deploy from visual studio 2017. I also did this in administrator mode.

I also tried to locate the "packageRecipe" parameter, but I cant find any reference to it anywhere. Anyone seen this kind of error before?

Comment: Are there any additional errors/warning in the error window? And could you try closing the solution and cleaning all the `obj` and `bin` folders from whole project.

Comment: The project is clear of errors. I tried your suggestion and clean the project manually and retried deploy. No change. Same error as before. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Could post your error info for us?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have tried to find any error information i can, but the only thing i get from visual studio is the output in the post. Is there any specific information you want to know? Then I can get that for you.

Comment: You could find the  Error list tab button in the bottom visual studio  window.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Oh so that was what you were looking for. That window is clean. No errors.

Comment: Please check this line `Parameter cannot be null or whitespace. Parameter name: packageRecipe`, could you share more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never figured out why my Visual Studio 2017 acted the way it did. I switched to visual studio 2015 and everything works perfectly now. It seems that Modern POS for Dynamics 365 is not yet compatibel with VS2017 for some odd reason.